# C++ not reading the last line when the file is edited by windows

Tags: c++, csv, file-io, ifstream

```
while (!file.eof())
{
    getline(file, line);
    if (!file.eof() && line.length() != 0)
    {
       //process line
    }
}
```

file is std::ifstream.
When I read a csv file using this, it does not read the last line of the CSV file if it is edited in Windows. However, this does not happen if we edit this file in UNIX and save.

What is the reason for this behaviour and what will be a possible fix for this?

Comment: Because you don't know how to examine the contents of the file, and determine whether the last line in the file has a trailing newline, or not, and your code breaks when it does not.

Comment: I didn't quite get you there. Assume at process line comment is replaced by a function to print the content of the line. My question is it does not print the last line of the file if it is edited by Windows. But works fine if it is edited in Unix

Comment: You repeated your question. And I am repeating my comment. What part of "determine whether the last line in the file has a trailing newline, or not" you did not understand?

Comment: `while (getline(file, line)) { /* process line */ }`

Comment: Search for "while (!file.eof()) always wrong" in Google.